# Copper coated neodymium magnets for battery connection?

Tags: magnet

I'm looking at making a quick disconnect battery that is attached with magnets. It looks like most magnets have a coating for abrasion and oxidation protection but no mention of conductivity.

Is it possible to coat the magnet in a dielectric then a conductive coating and run current through as a sort of battery connector? Would you even need the dialectic?

Comment: Hm, while you certainly can make some contact either way, you **really** would need to explain why that approach would be even comparable to using well-proven contacts (which solve the whole reliable contacting and release dilemma you get) that you just secure mechanically with a magnet.

Comment: This is for a quick swap system for a battery that only weighs 10g and normally has very small connectors that are difficult to work with and can take 20 seconds or more to fiddle with. It would also allow for easy balance charging for multi celled lion batteries. The batteries only last about 2 minutes each so swapping frequently is required.

Comment: It's a *battery*: good connections are paramount, and will not be achieved without proper contacts. pressing two conductive surfaces together does not make a reliable, low-ohmic connector. You really need a good metal contact – these exist and are cheap.  Copper coating doesn't do! It will oxidize!The idea of fixing these with a magnet is great, but really, don't try to make the magnet surface be the contact.

Comment: There ARE magnetic connectors out there that just about snap into place by themselves if you bring them close to each other. But they don't rely on the magnet itself to conduct. I am not sure if any are small enough for your needs. It is definitely an interesting idea and I am glad you asked about it.

Comment: https://www.amazingmagnets.com/t-plating_options.aspx  Ni-Cu-Ni coatings exist but does not solve other issues for current density and contact pressure, size , fit , adhesion to SS electrodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Marcus. Copper probably wouldn't be the way. The other problem is getting a good connection from magnet>pcb. I think if the magnets were not flat and more of a dimple in crater approach it would work better.

Comment: Plenty of drones and model aircraft have slide-in battery docking implemented with quite ordinary miniature connectors and some additional molded pieces for fixturing.

Comment: If you *were* going to do this, a brass coating would be far better than plain copper. But a different method altogether would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

Most neodymium magnets have a nickel based coating. It is pretty conductive anyway. Give it a go. I have a pile of magnets and a battery next to me so tried it, and it worked...

Think carefully if it's for a product, but for a home project, why not!

Comment: I'm looking for about 10 amps through anywhere from 14-100mm^2 of contact area depending on what's possible here with a higher performance coating. The problem isn't whether it would work but if it would be efficient.

Comment: @usernamechecksout So why did you ask "Is it possible..." if the problem "isn't whether it would work"? You should take the time to write the proper question from the beginning. Edit your question and add **all** of the information you gave in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible to get a results using the coating on a magnet for connectivity, it would seem a real unknown at 10 Amps. Trying to over-plate the surface would seem like an excise in futility as you'd have almost no control of the contact surface.

I'd suggest that you build your batteries with Pogo pins on the terminals and simply use the magnet to provide the contact pressure you need to compress the springs.
Most Pogo pins are limited in the current they carry because of the conduction thorough the spring, so you need multiple to supply 10A.
For example:
[image]

Those [above](https://www.harwin.com/products/P70-1000045R/) are rated at 2A. Clearly you could pass more current but would be advised to have at least 4 for each terminal.

Perhaps more engineering but more capable are spring loaded self wiping contacts such as [this](https://www.harwin.com/products/S1941-42R/):

[image]

Here the current rating is 9A so it's easily possible that this would provide service at 10A for your 2 minutes.

I'd normally consider [Mill-Max](http://file:///C:/Users/owner/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe/TempState/Downloads/014%20(1).pdf) for reliability, but they are higher cost and usually specified at about 3A peak per contact.

Answer (score -1):

Homopolar motors bank on the fact that a neodymium magnet has a conductive outer layer.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_motor

Comment: Thanks for the anonymous drive by....